# Simulating correlated data with Categorical and Continuous Variables

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, simulation

I am trying to simulate correlated data using the 'anysim' package in R. The software allows for correlations to be specified between categorical and continuous distributions. There are intermediate technical steps where it back-transforms a multivariate normal distribution to the original distributions. That's great since the data set I am trying to create involves both nominal and continous variables. Yet I don't understand how to interpret this 'correlation'. My intuition says I should use dummy variables for each level of the nominal variables. Then I need to specify the 'correlation' between either 0 or 1 and the level of the continuous variable.

This whole problem seems ambiguous. I understand the Pearson's correlation coefficient isn't defined for this situation. I also fear this procedure will introduce a linear relationship between 0 to 1 and the continuous scale.

I don't mind if the simulated data set isn't completely representative. We are using it in a psychological setting for a preregistration report, so we will get a real data set. This simulated one only serves to test what statistical models are sensible. If the data is a rough approximation, that's alright.

My question is how to interpret this 'correlation', and whether you think any severe problems will arise in this simulation. Of course, if you happen to know an alternative method to simulate such data, please feel free to post that as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give a more precise answer it would help to mention exactly which function you are using in the package, because 'the correlation' can indeed mean a lot of things. Pearson correlation applies well to normal bivariates, but there are others such as Spearman's rank correlation that do not make any parametric assumptions. An intermediate example is the [point-biserial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-biserial_correlation_coefficient) correlation, which was specifically developed for use between a continuous normal and binary variable.

There will not be an exact linear relationship between the binary and continuous scale unless the original correlation is exactly 1. In fact, the binary outcome will be a continuous outcome that was dichotomized, so as long as the underlying standard normal variables contain randomness so will the transformed outcomes.

I don't think there is anything particularly wrong with this approach, it is in fact one of the more common and straightforward methods of obtaining correlated random covariates. As you mention, an issue is that the multivariate normal from which you start is usually and readily characterized through Pearson correlation, but this exact correlation is not maintained through the transformation.

One alternative option is to switch to a non-parametric correlation coefficient, which should be preserved as long as the transformation is linear. Another option is to empirically tweak the multivariate normal correlation until you get the desired correlation, or whatever statistic that may be, in the target scale.

Comment: Pearson correlation definitely does not require bivariate normality.

Comment: You're right & I've edited my post, I never meant to imply that your data must be normally distributed to use Pearson correlation. Still, the point stands that it will break down when means and standard deviations don't characterize your data well.

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate answer. To estimate the correlated random variables, I am usnig the function 'EstCorrRVs' from the anySim package. (https://rdrr.io/github/itsoukal/anySim/man/EstCorrRVs.html.) This also shows the full code snippet I use. I don't see an option to use a point-biserial correlation within the function.

Comment: Regarding my other question, how would you explain this faux-Pearson correlation between a dummy variable and continuous variable? I want to fill the correlation matrix with estimates, but I don't know how to communicate this to a domain expert I am working with.

Comment: It seems like that function wants you to specify the *target* Pearson correlation, and will automatically create a covariance matrix from which to draw multivariate normals that will produce this correlation after transformation. This means that you're essentially stuck with Pearson as far as this package is concerned, but at least it's the correlation of the resulting distributions.  
  
Upon further reading about the point-biserial (I don't use it myself) it seems that this is mathematically just the regular Pearson correlation, so I'm not sure if that's any real help.

Comment: As to how to explain this to domain experts: I would recommend graphics, and maybe ask them to draw what they feel it should be like? The binary factor is really just two clouds of points next to one another (and the correlation is the degree to which points are separated on the other axis across clouds).

Comment: @PBulls Thank you for looking into this. This resolved my issue. Have a great day!